# How to create a variable in a foreach loop and use it outside the loop?

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I'm comparing 2 numbers entered to numbers in an xml file and then storing the result of each comparison in a variable ($n1, $n2). I'm then adding the total of each variable up and storing it in a new variable $total within the foreach loop. I've tried displaying the result in the loop but it shows both the result for correct and incorrect comparison as it loops around the whole xml.

I want to be able to use $total outside of the loop to display a result. When I echo $total outside the loop, its result is 0 no matter whether the comparisons are correct. When I echo it in the loop it has a value.

How to I  ensure the $total variable keeps its stored value outside of the loop?

```
$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];

$xml = simplexml_load_file('lottery2.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
if(isset($_POST['num1'])&& isset($_POST['num2']))
{
foreach($xml->children() as $record)
{ 
    if($record->num1 == $num1 || $record->num2 == $num1) 
     {
        $n1=1;
     } 
    else 
     {
        $n1=0;
     }
    if($record->num1 == $num2 || $record->num2 == $num2) 
     {
        $n2=1;
     } 
    else 
     {
        $n2=0;
     }

    $total= $n1+$n2;

}//end foreach

    if ($total=2) {
        echo "Jackpot is ".$record->jackpot ."<br />";
    } else {
        echo "No jackpot, sorry";
    }
```

Comment: `$total` needs to be defined outside the foreach loop, as it stands you're rewriting it at every iteration. So, define `$total` outside the loop and instead of doing `$total= $n1+$n2;` do `$total += $n1+$n2;`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you care about is whether both numbers were found, use booleans (no need for `$total`):

```
$n1 = false;//make true once we find 1st num
$n2 = false;//make true once we find 2nd num
foreach($xml->children() as $record){
    $n1 = $n1 || $record->num1 == $num1 || $record->num2 == $num1;
    $n2 = $n2 || $record->num1 == $num2 || $record->num2 == $num2;

    if($n1 && $n2) break; //we've found both. No need to keep looking
}//end foreach

if ($n1 && $n2) echo "Jackpot!";
else echo "No Jackpot, sorry";
```

Comment: And define `$total` outside of the `foreach` loop. I mean it will default to null(leaving aside the notice), and coercing will probably take care of that but still.

Comment: That has worked to add up the value of $total but now every time it finds the number entered, it sets $n1 and $n2 to amount that number appears in xml rather that setting it to 1 as I want. For example, if I enter correct numbers 11 + 4, $total becomes 359 instead of 2. Is there a way to set $n1 + $n2 to 1 regarldess of how many times the number is found in the xml?

Comment: I've updated my form so I've now got 6 entered numbers but only 3 need to be correct to display the jackpot. Is there a way of checking if 3 numbers are correct and collecting the $record->jackpot in the loop, which are associated with the 3 correct numbers, then displaying the jackpots? This is because there will be multiple jackpots based on the entered numbers

Comment: @A.Hollingsworth you're expanding the question beyond the original scope. If one of the answers solved the original problem, please select and upvote. To expand you just need to manipulate the statements inside the loop.  You can also collect the jackpot in a `$jackpot` var in the loop then echo that var outside

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ($total=2)
```

to

```
if ($total == 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare it outside the loop

```
 $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];
$total=0;
```

and concatenate the value.

```
 $total+=$num1+$num2;
```